# SQL passing many values (vector) through one parameter for the query/command

Tags: sql, firebird

First of all I want to say I'm using Firebird and do not know if this is problem with other database servers.

What I want to do is pass part of command string as parameter.

I have code like this:

```
using (FbConnection con = new FbConnection(M.Baza.connectionString))
{
    con.Open();
    using (FbCommand cmd = new FbCommand("DELETE FROM STAVKA WHERE VRDOK = @VRDOK AND BRDOK = @BRDOK AND ROBAID IN (@ROBAID)", con))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VRDOK", vrDok);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BRDOK", brDok);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ROBAID", robaId); //robaId is string which looks like this '15, 18, 16, 14, 28'

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        if (showMessage)
            MessageBox.Show("Stavke uspesno obrisane!");
    }
}
```

The code above is not working and it drops error

> unable to cast object of type 'system.Int32` to type 'system.iconvertible'

But when I write code like this:

```
using (FbConnection con = new FbConnection(M.Baza.connectionString))
{
    con.Open();
    using (FbCommand cmd = new FbCommand("DELETE FROM STAVKA WHERE VRDOK = @VRDOK AND BRDOK = @BRDOK AND ROBAID IN (" + robaId + ")", con))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VRDOK", vrDok);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BRDOK", brDok);

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        if (showMessage)
            MessageBox.Show("Stavke uspesno obrisane!");
    }
}
```

It works.

Why is this happening?

Let's say I have command like this `"SELECT " + columns + " FROM TABLE"` where `columns` is type of string which looks like this `column1, column2, column3` and it is working. How I can make same code look like this `"SELECT @COLUMNS FROM TABLE"` and pass that `@COLUMNS` just like I am passing parameters with `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@COLUMNS", columns);`

Comment: no, you can not pas MULTIPLE values as ONE parameter. Parameters are scalar, not vector. If your values are integer only - you may put them into query text directly. `IN` clause does not have one string value inside - it has a number (array, vector, list. you name it) of some scalar parameters (integer, float, date, anything). So if you would want to pass them as params, you have to make a separate parameter for every value within `IN`-list

Comment: Here are some alternative techniques you can use instead of mere "String splicing" (putting numbers directly into query text) or auto-generating the query with parameters like `@ROBAID_1` and `@ROBAID_2` and `@ROBAID_3` and so on.

Comment: As to the second part of your question (really, you should ask only on thing per question, not multiple things!), no you cannot parameterize the column list.

Comment: Okay.... Totally out of point but thanks for time...

Comment: `no you cannot parameterize the column list` @MarkRotteveel well, then there is `EXECUTE STATEMENT` and `EXECUTE BLOCK` :-D Though it is "dirty ugly hack" to abuse them for that.

Comment: That being said, there is a bug in the code. `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); if (showMessage) MessageBox.Show("Stavke uspesno obrisane!");` - here the program cheats on the user telling him things ("table Stavke was trimmed successfully") that did not happen yet (the transaction is not commited and maybe never would be).

Comment: @Arioch'The There is no point to use those, as the OP could simply already generate the required column list when building his query in C#.

Comment: I agree about "no practical point" but still that was not quite "impossible". Just made a sidenote.

Comment: w.r.t. `How can i implement part of text to command like i am implementing parameter` you only asked with details about one very specific case of parametrizing - parametrizing the values in the `IN`-list. If you want to "parametrise" any random part of SQL query - then you can use FB's `EXECUTE STATEMENT` command to achieve it. But it would be exactly the same string operation "+ sign" just executed in the Firebird ( there it would be "|| sign" ) not in C# and in a VERY indirect (error-prone and boilerplate-heavy) way.

Comment: Yea I want to "parametrize" any random part of SQL query but I am not sure how should I build my query inside c# code with `EXECUTE STATEMENT`

Comment: What Arioch'The tries to say is that you shouldn't parameterize parts of your SQL query. You need to dynamically build those parts in your C# code, only parameterize **values**. Just be aware of SQL injection risk if the dynamic parts of your query are user supplied.